# how to get only the first element of a touple list into an array

Tags: python, arrays, tuples, list-comprehension, python-3.3

I have (result from a query) `my_list = [('a',),('b',),('c',),('g',),('j',)]`
I want to translate it to `['a','b','c']`
What I have so far `r = [rs for rs in my_list if rs not in[('g',),('j',)]]`

This will fetch `('a',),('b',),('c',)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the first element of the tuple:

```
r = [rs[0] for rs in list if rs not in[('g',),('j',)]]
#       ^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inputs = [('a',),('b',),('c',),('g',),('j',)]

r = [left for (left,) in inputs if left not in ['g','j']]
```

Be careful that `list` is an important function in python, using it as a variable name will override it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get what the rules are for selecting items, but you want to [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) your initial list (`list` renamed to `l`):

```
[item for sublist in l[:3] for item in sublist]
```

This returns `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

In case you already know the structure of your input list, you do not need to filter each item. In case the filter rules are more complex that your current question suggests, you should specify them.